Zero Voltage Switching (ZVS) in Conventional Full-Bridge DC/DC Boost Converter
I am trying to design a Conventional Full-Bridge DC/DC Boost Converter with the following parameters (I am not sure if you need them);

Input voltage: 24 V (DC)
Output voltage: 400 V (DC)
Output current (max): 2.75 A
Output power: 1100 W
Switching frequency: 100 kHz

I have designed transformer but have not choose MOSFETs and their drivers. While doing researches about the design and topology, I came across with the term Zero Voltage Switching (ZVS). After searching ZVS, I understood its benefits and want to apply it into my circuit.
I want to ask you that how can I do ZVS in my circuit? I have seen phase shifted full-bridge but I am afraid if I am going to have to design my transformer and calculations again.
Do you know any way to do? Maybe placing a capacitor in parallel to the MOSFETs?
Thanks in advence.



I want to ask you that how can I do ZVS in my circuit?

You can't get ZVS (or soft switching, in general, which covers ZVS and ZCS) in a hard-switched (I think this is what you meant by "conventional") DC-DC converter. You need to make some changes in circuit and in control methods.
You'll quite possibly have to switch to either PSFB (phase-shifted full bridge) or FB LLC (full bridge LLC). The design phase of either can sometimes be annoying. Also the control can give you nightmares.
PS: The output power level already screams "PSFB".

Thank you so much for your valuable comment, sir. The reason why I do not want to change my topology was related to control and design considerations..

@NafiCanEreli taking the full advantage of soft switching is not free.
